# Shell Script for Menu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, menu

I am making a new Menu Driven Shell Script in linux, I have simplified my table to just hello and bye to make this simpler, below is my basic menu layout

```
# Menu Shell Script
#
echo ----------------
echo     menu
echo ----------------
echo [1] hello
echo [2] bye
echo [3] exit
echo ----------------
```

Basically I have the menu, I have been playing around with a few things recently but cant seem to get anything working as I am new to this, I think then next line would be

```
`read -p "Please Select A Number: " menu_choice`
```

but I am not sure what to do with the variable and what not.
I was wondering if anyone could help me with the next bit of code to simply get it to say hello when I press one, bye when 2 is pressed and exit when 3 when the user presses 3. It would be so much appreciated as I have been trying different ways for days and can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: You shouldn't put the `read` command in backticks. Just use it normally, and then test the variable `$menu_choice` with a `case` statement.

Comment: Do you have those backticks in your code, or was that just something you added to format your code for this post?

Comment: Any reason you're not using the built-in `select` command to display a menu?

Comment: I'm very new to this, been using it a week and i'm literally just teaching myself so i'm not sure about the select command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need those backticks for `echo...` and `read`

```
echo "----------------"
echo "    menu"
echo "----------------"
echo "[1] hello"
echo "[2] bye"
echo "[3] exit"
echo "----------------"

read -p "Please Select A Number: " mc
if [[ "$mc" == "1" ]]; then
    echo "hello"
elif [[ "$mc" == "2" ]]; then
    echo "bye"
else
    echo "exit"
fi
```

**Edit**

```
showMenu(){

echo "----------------"
echo "    menu"
echo "----------------"
echo "[1] hello"
echo "[2] bye"
echo "[3] exit"
echo "----------------"

read -p "Please Select A Number: " mc
return $mc
}


while [[ "$m" != "3" ]]
do
    if [[ "$m" == "1" ]]; then
        echo "hello"

    elif [[ "$m" == "2" ]]; then
        echo "bye"
    fi
    showMenu
    m=$?
done

exit 0;
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked a treat! Am i right in thinking there is a code to send this into a loop? so when i press one and it's said hello it doesnt just end?

Comment: @user2157995 I didn't get you, sorry, what loop? echo "hello" in loop?

Comment: All my code is in a file, when i open the file and press 1 it says hello then leaves the file and to choose another option i have to re-enter ./file_name to start again. Is there a code so when i press 1 it says hello then takes me back to the menu?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample

```
if [ $menu_choice -eq 1 ]
then
    echo hello
elif [ $menu_choice -eq 2 ]
then
    echo bye
elif [ $menu_choice -eq 3 ]
then
    exit 0
fi
```

or using case

```
case $menu_choice in
    1) echo hello
       ;;
    2) echo bye
       ;;
    3) exit 0
       ;;
esac
```

Comment: `eq` is not a comparison operator in `test`. ITYM `-eq` or `=`.